# Commutative ring Galois extension with two non-isomorphic Galois groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I'm currently studying about the generalisation of Galois Theory for commutative rings. I'm trying to find a good example that illustrates how this generalisations allows a Galois extension of a commutative ring $S$ over $R$ to have different associated Galois groups (non-isomorphic).

I've been trying to find a scenary where this happends. As I know, the natural case in which this occurs is when having the commutative ring $S_n=Fe_1\oplus Fe_2\oplus\cdots\oplus Fe_n$, where $e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0),$ where $1$ is in the $i$-th place (the $e_i$ are orthogonal idempotents). I've found I can always define a Galois extension from $S_n$ over $F(e_1+\cdots + e_n)$ with the group $G=\langle\sigma\rangle$, where $\sigma$ is any $n$-cycle (for simplicity I take the natural one $(123...n)$).

But I've tried up to $n=5$ and for these examples it doesn't seem I can find another group (non isomorphic to $\langle \sigma \rangle$) valid as Galois group of the extension.

So my question is, which is the easiest possible example (lowest possible $n$) of this kind where I can find two different and non-isomorphic Galois groups for a Galois extension of commutative ring $S_n$? I have assumed the easiest possible example where this happends is for a ring of the kind of those $S_n$, but I may be wrong, so in that case, which is an easier example?

Comment: Can you expand, what is "the Galois group"? $Aut(S/R)$ seems to be unambiguously well-defined for any ring extension.

Comment: @reuns The Galois group of the Galois extension $S$ over $R$ is a finite subgroup of $\text{Aut}(S)$ s.t. $R=S^G$ (elements of $S$ fixed by every element of $G$), and that also verifies that there are certain $x_1,...x_n,y_1,...y_n\in S$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sigma(y_i)=\delta_{1,\sigma}$ for all $\sigma\in G$. Isn't it true that there are commutative ring extensions that have different non-isomorphic Galois groups (this does not happend for field extensions, I'm talking about commutative ring extensions). Are you familiar with the concept of strongly distinct homomorphisms? Thanks for helping

Comment: @reuns the problem may be that in this particular example of commutative ring, that cannot happend. That fenomenon may only be possible while dealing with commutative rings of different kind (not a cartesian product of fields).

Comment: With $\delta_{1,\sigma}$ you meant times the 1 of $S$ ? (assumed to be unital)

Comment: @reuns With $\delta_{1,\sigma}$ i mean the Kronecker Delta (equals $1_S=(1,...,1)$ if $\sigma=1$ and $0$ in other case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong,

On $\Bbb{R}^4$

- there is the $\Bbb{Z/4Z}$ action generated by $\sigma:(a,b,c,d)\to (d,a,b,c)$
- but also a $\Bbb{Z/2Z}\times \Bbb{Z/2Z}$ action generated by $\rho:(a,b,c,d)\to (b,a,d,c),\phi:(a,b,c,d)\to (c,d,a,b)$

  ($\phi\rho=\rho \phi$ so it is clear that every element has order $2$).

The subring fixed by $\langle \sigma \rangle$ is $\Bbb{R}(1,1,1,1)$, same for the subring fixed by$\langle \rho,\phi \rangle$.

For the "invertibility of the matrix of conjugates" condition: in both case take $x_1=y_1=(1,0,0,0)$, $x_2=y_2=(0,1,0,0)$,$x_3=y_3=(0,0,1,0)$, $x_4=y_4=(0,0,0,1)$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i y_i=(1,1,1,1)$ and $x_i g(y_i)=0$ whenever $g\ne 1$.